# Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies [ECSCluster] in the Resources block of the template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

I have a condition to create or not the ECS Cluster and when I choose not to create it, indicating the boolean value false, Cloudformation returns the following error: Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies [ECSCluster] in the Resources block of the template.

Below is a snippet of my code for this error:

```
Parameters:
  
  NameNewECSCluster:
    Type: String

  NameOldECSCluster:
    Type: String

  CreationECSCluster: 
    Type: String
    AllowedValues: [true, false]

Conditions:
  CreationECSClusterSelected: !Equals [!Ref CreationECSCluster, true]

  ECSCluster:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Cluster
    Condition: CreationECSClusterSelected
    Properties:
      ClusterName: !Ref NameNewECSCluster
      CapacityProviders:
        - FARGATE
        - FARGATE_SPOT
      Tags:
        - Key: CLUSTER
          Value: !Ref NameNewECSCluster

  ECSService:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Service
    DependsOn: ListenerHTTPforALB
    Properties:
      ServiceName: !Sub ${ApplicationName}-${Environment}
      Cluster: !If [CreationECSClusterSelected, !Ref ECSCluster, !Ref NameOldECSCluster]
```

The problem only occurs when I refer to a Cluster already created, when I create the Cluster inside the template it does not.

Does anyone have an idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

If `CreationECSClusterSelected` is false, then `ECSCluster` does not exist and `!Ref ECSCluster` will result in the error. It does not matter the you have `!If`. Both false and true alternatives of your `If` **must be valid** as `If` gets executed after validation of your `If` statement.  You can try with:

```
 Cluster: !If [CreationECSClusterSelected, !Ref NameNewECSCluster, !Ref NameOldECSCluster]
```

Comment: Marcin, I made the change you said but still the same error: Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies [ECSCluster] in the Resources block of the template.

Now the !If looks like this:

Cluster: !If [CreationECSClusterSelected, !Ref NameNewECSCluster, !Ref NameOldECSCluster]

Comment: @DanielFulgido It's not possible to get same error, as new code does not even use ECScluster.